# Change column separator for CSV for entire rails application

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, csv

I am generating CSV using `CSV.generate` using the default column separator(",") in my rails application(`Rails 4.2.4 & ruby version ruby 2.2.4p230`).

I need to now update the column separator to `;`, I can do it like this `CSV.generate(:col_sep => ";")` but i will have to replace at many places.

I wanted to know if we can set the column separator at some generic place in the application which applies to all `CSV.generate` and not change at each individual place.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

`CSV::DEFAULT_OPTIONS` hash constant holds default values for options, including `col_sep`. There's no standard way to set or modify those defaults, since the hash is frozen. A little workaround (or maybe, a dirty hack) is necessary:

```
require 'csv'
modified_defaults = CSV::DEFAULT_OPTIONS.dup
modified_defaults[:col_sep] = ';'
CSV::DEFAULT_OPTIONS = modified_defaults.freeze
```

Probably the best place for that would be in `config/initializers/csv.rb`. This should make `csv` library globally available in your application and globally redefine the defaults.

This solution will cause warnings about redefining a constant. Remember that new default will be used not only by `.generate`, but all methods in `csv` library that accept the `col_sep` option.

Answer (score 0):

It's not (currently) an option that can be set globally. However, you could write a wrapper that overrides `initialize` and use it where you're currently using `CSV`.

```
class SSV < CSV
  # Uses Ruby 2.2.4 semantics instead of named parameters used in later versions.
  def initialize(data, options = Hash.new)
    super(data, options.merge(col_sep: ';'))
  end
end

SSV.generate('') { |ssv| ssv << ['foo', 'bar', ';'] } # => "foo;bar;\";\"\n"
```

(Make sure you wrap this in some tests.)